# Проблема с шаблонами в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Доброго времени суток!

Создал базу данных, по ней сформировал модель и тут возникла такая проблема:
только один шаблон генерации (`DbContext`) поддерживает событие фильтрацию (`myViewSource.Filter`)

```
Context.myTable.Local.Load();//заполнение
CollectionViewSource myViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)this.FindResource("myViewSource");
myViewSource = Context.myTable.Local;
```

остальные генераторы кода `Self-Tacking Entity`, `EntityObject` не поддерживают фильтрацию (`myViewSource.CanChangeLiveFiltering = false`), НО они могут обновляться `Context.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins`, `Context.myTable`) )

`DbContext` МОЖЕТ фильтровать и НЕ МОЖЕТ обновляться второй `Load` не помогает - я не знаю почему он не хочет это делать

Как мне быть, если мне нужна И фильтрация, И обновление? Есть такой шаблон, где есть все или нужно еще массивы создавать, чтобы хранить оригиналы записей в таблице и если понадобиться обновиться, то брать оттуда (но это какой-то самопал, хочется по-нормальному)?

СПАСИБО!

Comment: Хм, у вас база данных бежит в UI-потоке? Будет же зависать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подвисает немного при запуске всего приложения (загружаются все данные из `20+` таблиц), а само приложение работает без зависания.
`DBContext` хранит же в свойстве данные в `Local` - и я работаю с ней (обращений к базе данных уже нет), если нужно изменить что-нибудь, то  меняю это в `Local` потом вызываю `Context.SaveChanges()` и изменения переносятся в таблицу.
Но вот я думаю, чтобы переделать генерацию моделей по другому шаблону, например, `STE`, тогда локальную копию таблоицы (`Local`) мне нужно будет хранить в какой-нибудь `ObservableCollection`, думаю так сделать.